# Implement an Android floating window that can open the system input method list on any page

Tags: android

I want to implement a feature, a floating window, that allows users to click on any page (whether it's their own application or someone else's application) to pop up a list of input methods in the system. I can't get the context of other packages. Is there any other way to implement this function

```
String pageName = Utils.getTopActivityByUsageStatsManager(mContext).trim();
Context remoteContext = null;
try {
   ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(pageName, 0);
 remoteContext = mContext.createPackageContext(applicationInfo.packageName,     CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);                         
} catch (SecurityException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
if (remoteContext!=null){
  InputMethodManager imm =    (InputMethodManager)remoteContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.showInputMethodPicker(); 
}
```

Is there any other way to implement this function